Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_column(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given
I have a button
<a href="like.php?type=user&id=<?php echo $user_data['userid'] ?>"> 
<input id="post_button" type="button" value="Sledi <?php echo $mylikes ?>" style="margin-right: 10px; background-color: #119f8a; width: auto;"> </a>

After clicking the button I get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_column(): Argument #1 ($array)
must be of type array, null given in
E:\xampp\htdocs\MyBook\classes\user.php:94 Stack trace: #0
E:\xampp\htdocs\MyBook\classes\user.php(94): array_column(NULL,
'userid') #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\MyBook\like.php(42):
User->follow_user('986841892650929...', 'user', '6781') #2 {main}
thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\MyBook\classes\user.php on line 94

The error refers to the line $user_ids = array_column($likes,"userid"); in function follow_user
public function follow_user($id,$type,$mybook_userid) 
{
    if($id == $mybook_userid && $type == 'user'){
            return;
        }

        $DB = new Database();
        
        //save likes details
        $sql = "select following from likes where type='$type' && contentid = '$mybook_userid' limit 1";
        $result = $DB->read($sql);

        if(is_array($result)){
//print_r($result);die;
            $likes = json_decode($result[0]['following'],true);
            $user_ids = array_column($likes,"userid");
 
            if(!in_array($id, $user_ids)) {

                $arr["userid"] = $id;
                $arr["date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                $likes[] = $arr;
                $likes_string = json_encode($likes);

                $sql = "update likes set following = '$likes_string' where type='$type' && contentid = '$mybook_userid' limit 1";
                $DB->save($sql);

                $user = new User();
                $single_post = $user->get_user($id);
            } else {
                $key = array_search($id, $user_ids);
                unset($likes[$key]);

                $likes_string = json_encode($likes);
                $sql = "update likes set following = '$likes_string' where type='$type' && contentid = '$mybook_userid' limit 1";
                $DB->save($sql);
            }
        } else {
            $arr["userid"] = $id;
            $arr["date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $arr2[] = $arr;
            $following = json_encode($arr2);
            $sql = "insert into likes (type,contentid,following) values ('$type','$mybook_userid','$following')";
            $DB->save($sql);
        }
}

print_r($result) returns:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [following] => ) )

It is empty because the column following for that query is empty.
Table likes looks like this:

It seems that when there is already a value in column likes, and when function needs to write in column following, this error accours.
Any ideas?


You appear to have a button inside a hyperlink. That's not valid HTML (and even if it was, it would be pretty nonsensical anyway - when a click happens, should it honour the link's href, or submit whatever form the button is part of??)



Array ( [0] => Array ( [following] => ) ) ...if that's what is in $result then it seems your query returned 1 row, and the "following" field in that was empty. We don't know what values you provided for $type and $mybook_userid when you tested this, so we don't know which row in your table the query would select. However, we can see from your screenshot that many of the rows have an empty "following" column, so this is not a surprise. When giving us an example like this, always provide the input data you used, so it's clear what will happen as a result.


....Therefore it's obvious that $likes = json_decode($result[0]['following'],true); will not work because there's nothing to decode. This then causes the error with array_column, because you got null from the json_decode and then passed that to array_column. So...you've understood the error already I think, but the question is - what do you want to happen in cases like this? We don't know what logic your system is trying to apply here.  Maybe you need to test if $likes is null and, if it is, create an empty array to start of the list of followers?

e.g. something like $likes = json_decode($result[0]['following'],true); if ($likes == null) {$likes = []; } $user_ids = array_column($likes,"userid");

P.S. It seems that when there is already a value in column likes, and when function needs to write in column following, this error accours...no, it's nothing to do with the likes column, because your query and code doesn't try to use that column at all. It's simply a problem which occurs when the following column is empty.

@ADyson adding an empty array solved the issue.
